# Unbound datagridview gives string datetime is not valid for column expiry date

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

[image]following is the code which i used to create the unbound datagridview

Private Sub Initilaize_grid()
        Dim Itemcode As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim desp As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim type As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim uom As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim batch_no As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim expiry_date As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim qty As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim unit_price As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim disc As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim grossamt As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim disc_p As New DataGridViewColumn
        Dim netamt As New DataGridViewColumn

```
    With Itemcode
        .Name = "Itemcode"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "ITEM CODE"
        .Width = 150
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With

    With desp
        .Name = "desc"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "Description"
        .Width = 250
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With type
        .Name = "type"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "Type"
        .Width = 50
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With uom
        .Name = "uom"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "UOM"
        .Width = 60
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With batch_no
        .Name = "batch"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "Batch"
        .Width = 77
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With expiry_date
        .Name = "expiry"
        .ValueType = GetType(Date)
        .DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        .HeaderText = "Expiry"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With qty
        .Name = "qty"
        .ValueType = GetType(Integer)
        .HeaderText = "Qty"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With unit_price
        .Name = "unitp"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Unit Price"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With disc
        .Name = "disc"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Discount"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With

    With disc_p
        .Name = "discp"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Disc(%)"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    End With
    With grossamt
        .Name = "gamt"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Gross Amount"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With netamt
        .Name = "namt"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Net Amount"
        .Width = 125
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With dgitemlist
        .Columns.Add(Itemcode)
        .Columns.Add(desp)
        .Columns.Add(type)
        .Columns.Add(uom)
        .Columns.Add(batch_no)
        .Columns.Add(expiry_date)
        .Columns.Add(qty)
        .Columns.Add(unit_price)
        .Columns.Add(grossamt)
        .Columns.Add(disc_p)
        .Columns.Add(disc)
        .Columns.Add(netamt)




    End With
End Sub
```

i am getting the following error when i enter date in the expiry column..i am entering date as mmddyyyy..even yyyymmdd format gives the attached error as string is not recognised as a valid datetime..

Answer (score 0):

the DefaultCellStyle.Format you provide is only used for output. not for parsing your input. guess you have to input your date according to the localization settings of your windows system (including slashes or dots between the date parts)

Comment: did you realize that the month probably is the first part of the date string? so 13/03/2013 is invalid ...